# Start appium and run nunit test from shell script

Tags: node.js, appium

Here is my script:

```
node ${APPIUM_PATH}/bin/appium.js
nunit-console AppiumTest.dll
```

The problem is that when appium starts it takes control over console and I can't run any more commands until it's stopped.

Alternatively I tried this:

```
node ${APPIUM_PATH}/bin/appium.js &
nunit-console AppiumTest.dll
```

which lets me run 2 commands simultaneously, but in this case it ignores the delay required for server to start.

Comment: Put sleep before running nunit test?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the nunit process should kick off after Appium listener has started. So you have listen to output from the first command and then invoke the nunit. Below is the nodejs version using javascript as it is quite easy in nodejs to listen to output stream from one process and kickoff another process.

Below is the syntax using nodejs . Since appium has already installed nodejs, create a js file (ex : AutoStart.js) in appium directory and run `node AutoStart.js`

Below is the code which is now on git hub - > link [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/sham332/ab4365cfd1538856d2bf)

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

child = exec("node bin/appium.js",function(error,stdout,stderr){
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }

  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

});

child.stdout.on('data',
    function(data){
    var buff = new Buffer(data).toString('utf8');
    console.log( buff);

    if(buff.match(/Appium REST http interface listener/))
    {
        console.log("Server is started");
        var nunitProcess = exec("nunit-console AppiumTest.dll", function(error,stdout,stderr){
              if (error !== null) {
                    console.log('error starting nUnit ' + error);
                  }

        })
    }
    else console.log("not started");

});
```